# better practice ? jquery

Tags: jquery, function, binding

Hey what is the best way of binding a jquery function to an a link ?

The way I am doing it at the moment is

```
<a href="" id="click">Click here</a>

$('#click').click(......
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way is fine.

Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 1):

The recommended method now is to use `on()`:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  //...
});
```